# How can I get a window position (x,y) created by using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

How can I get a window position (x,y) created by using OpenCV?

- I can create a named window: [`namedWindow("my window");`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#namedwindow)
- I can move this window: [`moveWindow("my window", x, y);`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#movewindow)

But how can I get current position's coordinates of this window?

Also, there is function [`void loadWindowParameters("my window");`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html#loadwindowparameters), which can as written:

> **loads** size, **location**, flags, trackbars value, zoom and panning
>   location of the window window_name

But does it load these parameters **to where**? Declaration of this function does not return anything - get only window name and return `void`.

Comment: `loadWindowParameters` probably loads the parameters saved -somewhere- by `saveWindowParameters`.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Can you give an example, how to work with these functions `loadWindowParameters()`/`saveWindowParameters()` which get only 1 parameter? I successfully using OpenCV, but I don't understand these functions.

Comment: @Alex I believe those functions are for internal house keeping of OpenCV only. Not for *us users*. Maybe take a look at the source: [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/04f16965d5c05106cf41b950de67188dbc33f1d7/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp#L253) and [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/04f16965d5c05106cf41b950de67188dbc33f1d7/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp#L844).

Comment: @nils Thank you, may be this is true. But how can I get window location by using other functions?

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I don't have an instant solution. But I would look into `cvGetWindowHandle` which returns a platform-specific handle to the window (HWND, GTK, Carbon, ...) and go from there.

Comment: There is feature request for it: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4351 I'm waiting for progress :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until [the feature request](http://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4351) for this feature gets done, if you need this functionality and can't wait, you can implement it yourself. You'll need the opencv source code, then you'll have to edit some opencv files and rebuild part of opencv. 
I followed the source code for **moveWindow()** as a model.

That's what I did:

add to **opencv/sources/modules/highgui/source/window_w32.cpp** this function (I added it just below the **cvMoveWindow** definition):

```
CV_IMPL void cvGetWindowRect( const char* name, int &x, int &y, int &width, int &height)
{
    CV_FUNCNAME( "cvGetWindowRect" );

    __BEGIN__;

    CvWindow* window;
    RECT rect;

    if( !name )
        CV_ERROR( CV_StsNullPtr, "NULL name" );

    window = icvFindWindowByName(name);
    if(!window)
        EXIT;

    GetWindowRect( window->frame, &rect );
    x = rect.left;
    y = rect.top;
    width = rect.right - rect.left;
    height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    __END__;
}
```

and add its declaration in **opencv/sources/modules/highgui/include/opencv2/highgui_c.h** :

```
CVAPI(void) cvGetWindowRect( const char* name, int &x, int &y, int &width, int &height);
```

This alone would allow you to use the **cvGetWindowRect** from C/C++ to get the window rect. But if you want to use the C++ interface or the python interface (as I do) you can edit two files more:

add to **opencv/sources/modules/highgui/source/window.cpp** this function:

```
void cv::getWindowRect( const String& winname, CV_OUT int &x, CV_OUT int &y, CV_OUT int &width, CV_OUT int &height)
{    
    cvGetWindowRect(winname.c_str(), x, y, width, height);
}
```

and add its declaration in **opencv/sources/modules/highgui/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp** :

```
CV_EXPORTS_W void getWindowRect( const String& winname, CV_OUT int &x, CV_OUT int &y, CV_OUT int &width, CV_OUT int &height);
```

Then you'll have to rebuild the **opencv_highgui** project (I do this for windows with Visual Studio 2015). If you need the python bindings then rebuild the **opencv_python3** project too. The CV_EXPORTS_W and CV_OUT macros are needed to expose the function and recognize the output parameters when building the python bindings. From python you'll get a 4-tuple as return value, ->eg:

```
>>> cv2.getWindowRect("my window")
(1024, 0, 817, 639)
```

For the python bindings you'll have to copy the new **cv2.cp35-win_amd64.pyd** and **opencv_highgui300.dll** to the **PythonEnv\Lib\site-packages**.